# Vim plugin "command t" throws an error

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I am new to Vim and just installed `Command T` plugin using `vundle`. When I want to use it inside Vim I got following error

```
Error detected while processing function commandt#CommandTShowFileFinder:
line    2:
LoadError: /Users/xafar/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/finder.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- command-t/ext
```

I have ruby version `ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]` on my mac os x with `Mavericks`.

**How can I resolve this problem?**

Comment: This error makes me think you do not have Command-T installed correctly. Please review the install instructions again. As an alternative you can use a pure vimscript plugin like [CtrlP.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) as your fuzzy finder.

Answer (score 1):

Simply installing Command-T from Vundle will not make it run correctly. It still needs to be compiled.

[From the Command-T install guide](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt) -

```
Compiling Command-T ~

The C extension must be built, which can be done from the shell. If you use a
typical Pathogen, Vundle or NeoBundle set-up then the files were installed inside
`~/.vim/bundle/command-t`. A typical VAM installation path might be
`~/.vim/vim-addons/command-t`.

Wherever the Command-T files were installed, you can build the extension by
changing to the `ruby/command-t` subdirectory and running a couple of commands
as follows:

  cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t
  ruby extconf.rb
  make

Note: If you are an RVM or rbenv user, you must build CommandT using the same
version of Ruby that Vim itself is linked against. You can find out the
version that Vim is linked against by issuing following command inside Vim:

  :ruby puts "#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"
```